# on the fly variable creation in php

Tags: php

I have the following case.
I have a class without variables, which by mistake sets a value to a variable that 'does not exists', in its constructor. The outcome is that the variable is created on the fly and it is viable as long as the class instance exists.

**myClass.php**

```
class myClass {
    public function __construct($var)
    {
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    public function printVar() {
        echo $this->var. "</br>";
    }
}
```

**tester.php**

```
include("myClass.php");

$myClass = new myClass("variable");
$myClass->printVar();

var_dump($myClass);
```

And when I run the `tester.php` the output is the following

```
variable
object(myClass)#1 (1) { ["var"]=> string(8) "variable" }
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening? Can you point me to any documentation lemma that explains this behavior?

Is it possible to avoid something like this overloading the `__set()` function?

Comment: Hum, don't get this. You tell your class that $this->var equals the string "variable" so when you var_dump it it tell you that the class has a variable called "var" and it's equal to "variable".... So what is the problem?

Comment: you have variables and you are setting it in your constructor ...

Comment: What's actually going wrong? I don't see anything wrong

Comment: the thing is that i am not defining `private $var` or anything inside the class

Comment: @Athafoud: that's standard PHP. you can create a variable anytime you want just by assigning something to it. doesn't matter if that var is class attribute or a "bare" variable.

Comment: @athafoud this is intended. Your using this in a constructor which will create the internal reference. What you are seeing Is completely normal

Comment: Ok! i didn't know that this is normal! Thank you for your time.

Comment: @BCartolo the question you mentioned answers the 'how to avoid it' part. But not they why. However is a good insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because php don't make it mandatory to declare before assigning value to it. But you should always declare variable in class as it increases readability of your code and also you can specify accessibility of variable to be public or private.

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking at creating vars on the fly based on a string you pass, you might want to check on $$vars, yes, two time '$' if i got your problem correctly this time

Comment: Variable variables are used to create a variable from a string which already has a value. I think OP is looking for a way to create variables without setting them explicitly

Comment: I am aware of this,but this is not the case